# Limit domain part of email using regex

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have a regex for email validation, what I wanna do is limit the characters for the domain part, I know that I will use this {1,10} but I don't know where should I put it. Thank you

```
/(?!.*\.{2})^([a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0]+(\.[a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0]+)*|"((([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7e\u00A0]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f\u00A0]))*(([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?")@(([a-z\d\u00A0]|[a-z\d\u00A0][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0]*[a-z\d\u00A0])\.)+([a-z\u00A0]|[a-z\u00A0][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0]*[a-z\u00A0])\.?$/i
```

Comment: By domain, do you mean everything after the `@`? So the total length of everything after that should be between 1 and 10 inclusive?

Comment: This question is by no means a duplicate of [How to validate an email address in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript) since the  regex is already doing what tha thread deals with. The problem is adding an extra requirement for the domain part of the email here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `(?![^@]{11})` after `^` to disallow 11 characters other than `@` at the start of string:

```
(?!.*\.{2})^(?![^@]{11})([a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0]+(\.[a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0]+)*|"((([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7e\u00A0]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f\u00A0]))*(([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?")@(([a-z\d\u00A0]|[a-z\d\u00A0][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0]*[a-z\d\u00A0])\.)+([a-z\u00A0]|[a-z\u00A0][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0]*[a-z\u00A0])\.?$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/anDiSP/1/)

Comment: yes, Thank you for this. I have limited the domain and local part in regex using this 
Yes! thank you for this. I have also fixed this, limiting the domain and local part using this:
`/(?!.*\.{2})^([a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0]{1,65}(\.[a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0]+)*|"((([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7e\u00A0]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f\u00A0]))*(([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?")@(([a-z\d\-\u00A0]|[a-z\d\u00A0][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0][a-z\d\-\u00A0]{0,253})\.)+([a-z\u00A0]|[a-z\u00A0][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0]*[a-z\u00A0])\.?$/i`